# maxifs and averagesif for data on certain dates

Tags: excel, function

I have a table with names in column B and dates in row 1. The rest of the tables is the sales amount for the employee listed in column B on the date in row 1.

I want to find the max and the average for certain days. For example we have 12 sales on various days a quarter. I want to be able to find the max sales amount on days days that we had sales, and the days we didn't have sales as well as the averages sales amount on the days we had sales and the days we didn't have sales.

[image: report]

[image: data]

Something like this. I can find the row that the data is in using match: =MATCH(A2,data!B:B,0) I can find the if is a sale using max and maxifs in an arrary: `{=MAX(MAXIFS(data!$C2:$N2,data!$C$1:$N$1,report!$M$1:$P$1))}` or using `=AGGREGATE(14,4,MAXIFS(data!$C2:$N2,data!$C$1:$N$1,report!$M$1:$P$1),1)`

There is a problem with finding the max if it is not a sale. I am not sure why. I tried: `=AGGREGATE(14,4,MAXIFS(data!$C2:$N2,data!$C$1:$N$1,"<>"&report!$M$1:$P$1),1)` & `{=MAX(MAXIFS(data!$C2:$N2,data!$C$1:$N$1,"<>"&report!$M$1:$P$1))}`

I can find the average if it is a sale if there is data for every day, but not if there is data missing. Then I get a `#DIV/0` error.

I think there are 2 issues. 
1) the `"<>"&report!$M$1:$P$1`  is not working for an array of dates
2) The average doesn't like it if there is not a number in the cell

Does anyone have any ideas on these?

Comment: "The average doesn't like it if there is not a number in the cell" > try replacing `average(<range>)` with `aggregate(1,<range>)` function .. does it work?

Comment: It did not. Thank you for the suggestion